# Long Text Area field in javascript custom button

Tags: javascript, custom-button, long-text-area

I have a custom button (JavaScript) which copies the Description field from Event to my custom Object like this:

> summary.Discussion_Topics__c = '{!Event.Description}';

Both fields are of Long Text Area(32000) type.
The button works fine when the Description has one line. When it includes multiple lines the javascript throws an exception. I would like to retain the formatting and copy the Description with multiple line.
Can that be achieved? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [JSENCODE Visualforce function](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) will escape the line feeds and other unsafe characters:

```
summary.Discussion_Topics__c = '{!JSENCODE(Event.Description)}';
```

This works in custom button JavaScript too e.g. in a custom "Execute JavaScript" button on Account:

```
var d = '{!JSENCODE(Account.Description)}';
alert(d);
```

Comment: Does  JSENCODE available for a custom button JS?

Comment: @Dedo Yes - see the example I added to the answer.